# Can database objects be made case insensitive while keeping strings case sensitive?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, collation, case-sensitive

In Microsoft SQL Server (2014) it is possible to choose between a case insensitive and case sensitive collation.

My reason for using a case-sensitive collation would be to make `"test" = "TEST"` return `false`.

Yet, what I would like to preserve is that when a table `"TEST"` exists, writing a query like `select * from test;` would still work. When the database has a case-sensitive collation it doesn't, because I would need to write it like `select * from TEST;`

Is there a way to set "object collation" and "string collation" separably?

Comment: Not at a computer but could you try `WHERE 'test' COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN = 'TEST';`?

Comment: You can have collations set at multiple levels, but there is no such "string or text only" collation setting. You can set it at the server, database, column, and as @AaronBertrand shows, expression. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177439(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mostly "yes", depending on how "automagic" you want everything to work.

First: *Database* identifier Collation (i.e. object names, column names, index names, etc) is taken from the Database's default Collation. That will determine the Collation of columns such as `sys.objects.name`, etc. So to do this, you can create or alter the Database to have a case-Insensitive Collation, such as `Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC`. This will allow you to have a table `TEST` that will be valid in queries such as `select * from test;`.

Server-scoped identifier Collation (e.g. Database names) is handled by the Instance's default Collation.

Second: If a Database's default Collation is case-Insensitive, then expressions that are entirely string literals and/or variables and/or output-parameters and/or UDF return values will be treated as case-Insensitive. For these expressions you would need to override that default behavior, per expression, using the `COLLATE` clause.

For example:

```
/* take database default collation behavior */
IF ('test' = 'TEST')
BEGIN
  PRINT 'Case-Insensitive';
END;
ELSE
BEGIN
  PRINT 'Case-Sensitive';
END;
-- ? result depends on the default collation of the "current" database ?


/* force case-sensitive */
IF ('test' = 'TEST' COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CS_AS_SC)
BEGIN
  PRINT 'Case-Insensitive';
END;
ELSE
BEGIN
  PRINT 'Case-Sensitive';
END;
-- Case-Sensitive


/* force case-insensitive */
IF ('test' = 'TEST' COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC)
BEGIN
  PRINT 'Case-Insensitive';
END;
ELSE
BEGIN
  PRINT 'Case-Sensitive';
END;
-- Case-Insensitive
```

Expressions between string columns and either string literals or variables will use the Collation of the string column, and if the Collation for the column is case-sensitive, then the expression will be evaluated as case-sensitive without needing to use the `COLLATE` clause.

By default, newly created columns that do *not* specify the `COLLATE` clause will inherit the Database's default Collation. In this case, you will need to specify something like `COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CS_AS_KS_WS_SC` for all `VARCHAR` / `NVARCHAR` columns that you want to be sensitive across all 4 categories (plus support Supplementary Characters).

PLEASE NOTE: Be very cautious about using a binary Collation (i.e. `Latin1_General_100_BIN2`) to get an accent/case/kana/width sensitive Collation; binary Collations are *not* truly case-sensitive.

Comment: When asking for a hand on StackExchange, you tend to get a whole arm :) Thanks for the in depth answer!

Comment: Could you explain why binary collations are not "truly" case-sensitive?

Comment: @kyooryu Yes, I can :-). I now have a blog post devoted to that question: [No, Binary Collations are not Case-Sensitive](https://sqlquantumleap.com/2017/07/13/no-binary-collations-are-not-case-sensitive/). Enjoy!